# RegEx for identifying a date followed by a special pattern

Tags: regex, vba, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a pattern of strings/values occurring at different interval. The Pattern is as follows:
 **30/09/2016  2,085,669  0          0        UC      No**

1. Date>SPACE>Number separated by comma>SPACE> NUMBER> SPACE> NUMBER> SPACE>STRING>SPACE>NUMBER

How do i identify this and extract from a cell. I have been trying to use regex to solve this problem. Please note the pattern can occur at any instance in single cell. Viz.

1. Somestring(space)(30/09/2016  2,085,669  0          0        UC      No)(space) More string
2. Somemorestring(space)(30/09/2016  2,085,669  0          0        UC      No)
3. Brackets are for illustration only

To identify for date I am using the below regex, not the best way, but does my job.

```
(^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$)
```

How to stitch this with remaining pattern?

Comment: Is `No` a number as in 1 or more digits?

Comment: "No" is a string

Answer (score 2):

You are only matching the date like part between the anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

Note that if you only want to match the value you can omit the parenthesis `()` to make it a capturing group around the expression.

You could extend it to:

```
^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d+(?:,\d+)+ \d+ \d+ [A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}` Match date like pattern
- `\d+(?:,\d+)+` Match 1+ digits and repeat 1+ times matching a comma and a digit
- `\d+ \d+` Match two times 1+ digits followed by a space
- `[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+` Match 2 times 1+ chars a-z followed by a space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPHmrh/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to extract the date from anywhere in a string, this expression uses two capturing groups before and after the date, and the middle group captures the desired date:

```
(.*?)(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})(.*)
```

You may not want to use start ^ and end $ chars and it would work.

[image]

If you wish to match and capture everything, you might just want to add more boundaries, and match patterns step by step, maybe similar to this expression:

```
(.*?)(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})\s+([0-9,]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(No)(.*)
```

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/7UavU4/1) can help you to edit/modify/change your expressions as you wish.

[image]

I have added extra boundaries, just to be safe, which you can simplify it.

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualize your expressions:

[image]

Comment: No I want the entire series to be extracted out as laid out in the pattern